# Keras CNN Model Training time

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have created a Binary Image Classifier, and when I run my code, I get training times from 1 to 2 hours. How can I reduce it?
This is what my code is:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Input
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import Model

num_classes = 2 
# This returns a tensor
inputs = Input(shape=(150,150,3))

x = Conv2D(16,(1,1), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu',)(inputs)
x = Conv2D(16,(3,3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(inputs)

x = Conv2D(32,(1,1), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu',)(inputs)
x = Conv2D(32,(3,3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(inputs)

x = Conv2D(64,(1,1), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu',)(inputs)
x = Conv2D(64,(3,3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(inputs)

x = Conv2D(128,(1,1), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu',)(inputs)
x = Conv2D(128,(3,3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(inputs)


x = Flatten()(inputs)
predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid')(x)

# This creates a model that includes
# the Input layer and three Dense layers
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', #https://github.com/keras- 
team/keras/issues/5034
          #loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I used ImageDataGenerator for preprocessing of my images:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "/content/drive/apagdata/train",
    target_size=(150,150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "/content/drive/apagdata/test",
    target_size=(150,150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2000,
    epochs=50,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=800)
model.save_weights('first_try.h5')
```

I have only 169 images in total for my data set. The reason is that I am trying to build a basic model before I implement my model on to all my data.

Comment: Are you using GPU or CPU?

Comment: This is done Google Colab, GPU

Answer (score 0):

**See Update Below**

Some possible speed improvements apart from using the GPU:

1. If the images are binary, then your inputs can be `Input(shape=(150,150))` instead of 3-channel
2. Instead of having `16 -- 32 -- 64 -- 128` conv filters, try lesser, like `8 -- 16 -- 16 -- 32`, check at what point you stop getting more validation accuracy
3. You can actually drop the `1 x 1` convolutions altogether. The `1 x 1` convolutions are usually used before `3 x 3` and `5 x 5` convolutions for dimensionality reduction. In your case, that's probably not needed. Even if you want to use it, the `1 x 1` convolution should output less number of channels to so that `3 x 3` convolutions can operate on lesser channels and output more channels, making the whole process faster. For example, 150 x 150 x 256 input -> 3 x 3 x 256 convolution is slower than 150 x 150 x 256 input -> 1 x 1 x 64 convolution -> 3 x 3 x 256 convolution. See how 256-D output is first mapped to 64-D and then again to 256-D. You are not doing this
4. You can subsample your output more by increasing the stride to `(2,2)` in the max-pooling operation, at least for the last three max-pooling layers
5. Unrelated to speed, but if you are using `categorical_crossentropy` with one-hot labels, you may want to use `softmax` instead of `sigmoid` (unless your problem in multi-label)

On GPU, this should not take more than 10 minutes I think given you have only about 170 images.

## Update

I actually didn't pay much attention to the correctness of the architecture itself but your comment made me think otherwise.

Your network is basically this:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(150,150,3))
x = MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(inputs)
x = Flatten()(inputs)
predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid')(x)
```

This is because instead of giving the output of second convolution as the input of max-pooling, you are throwing it away and performing max-pooling on inputs again. See this:

```
x = Conv2D(16,(1,1), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu',)(inputs)
x = Conv2D(16,(3,3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same')(inputs)  # should be x here instead of inputs
```

Apart from this, the answer at @Alaroff is the main reason.

Comment: Also it seems that my Convs dont appear in the model summary.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `fit_generator` with a `batch_size=32` and specifying `steps_per_epoch=2000`, meaning that you end up feeding to your network a total of 64000 images per epoch. You would *usually* like to use something like one unique image per epoch with, e.g. `steps_per_epoch = no_train_samples // batch_size + 1` (same applies also to `validation_steps`). However, given that you have *only* 169 training samples, you might want to go with a larger number of steps to minimize the Keras´ overhead in switching between the train and validation phases in-between the epochs.

Also **consider downsampling your training images prior to training** (your input is 150x150 px anyway), to save on decompression overhead (especially, if you have large PNG-files to work with).

Furthermore, on the Colab, **you are not always granted the entire GPU**, but may be sharing it with other users. This fact may also hit the overall performance.

Finally, pay attention to where you stream your data from. Is it your mounted Google drive? The **low bandwidth / high latency of I/O may be an issue** on Colab as well.